# ArgumentNullException when switching from Blend to VS 2012

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend, blend

I'm getting the following error message in the designer when switching from Expression Blend to Visual Studio 2012:

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: uriString
```

Despite the error I can compile, run a debug my project. However, I can't see the designer.
At the beginning Iit was working OK, but after doing some changes I got the error above.

I've found a similar post: [Unhandled exception prevents me from opening a project in Blend 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15636427/unhandled-exception-prevents-me-from-opening-a-project-in-blend-2012). There mention that it could be due to the project is referencing a .Net 2.0 assembly (it was posted 2013/03/26). However, I would like to know if this is the root cause or is there another reason? If so, what other solutions can be done to fix it?

Comment: An ArgumentNullException is thrown when you pass a null reference to a method that needs an argument (not null) passed to it. So start by looking for a method where you are failing to pass a parameter for the uriString argument as listed in your error message above. What form does the error message take? How about posting some code and the stack trace..?

Comment: Hi adaam. I guess I found why the error was throwing. The thing is that for some reason the MainWindow.xmal.cs file had the following in its main class: public partial class MainWindow: Page { . . .}. I just  remove it and the designer appears. The only detail is that everytime after runing the application the errors appears again and I have to click on the cleanup option to have the designer back